# How can I get a stack trace into client code with the MongoDB Node.js driver?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've noticed that MongoDB errors offer rather useless stack traces, pointing only within the driver's internals. The line of code in the client that triggered the error is not output:

```js
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('...', { useNewUrlParser: true }, async (err, client) => {
  try {
    // some mongo client code...
    // some more mongo client calls...
    await client.db().collection('nonexistent').drop();
    // yet more mongo client calls...
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
  client.close();
});
```

Here's the output from that:

```
MongoError: ns not found
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/home/dandv/mongostack/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:443:61)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:200:13)
    at processMessage (/home/dandv/mongostack/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:364:10)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/home/dandv/mongostack/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:533:15)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:200:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:290:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:271:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:226:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:166:17) {
  ok: 0,
  errmsg: 'ns not found',
  code: 26,
  codeName: 'NamespaceNotFound',
  name: 'MongoError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}
```

If there's more than one mongo driver call in the try/catch block, it's impossible to tell which one generated the error.

Is there a way to have those stack traces lead up to client code?

Comment: Might try longjohn: https://github.com/mattinsler/longjohn

Comment: Did you found a solution?